# Chart.js add to onhover text

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

New to chart.js and I cannot find a way in their documentation to add more information to labels:

[image]

What I got so far:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Greennnnnn", "Purple", "Orange", "Black"],
        datasets: [
        {
            label: 'DistanceA',
            data: [12, 16, 3, 5, 2, 8, 4],
            borderColor: ['rgba(86, 244, 66,1)'],
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'DistanceB',
            data: [5, 2, 4, 10, 6, 3, 7],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
    },

    options: {
        events: ['click'],
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    stepSize: 2
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"> </script>
```

In this image I want the label to additional information which I provide myself. Is there any way of doing this and staying within the bounds of the chart.js library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable in place of `"Greennnnnn"`. Just dynamically create the labels array, and pass that array in.